# Eclipse does not build C++ files

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation

I am trying to compile on Eclipse a project with C and C++ files (.c and .cpp)

I have an error code indicating at linking step that one of my function is not referenced (`undefined reference to 'main_application'`), and after some investigation I could spot that although I can find it in the project code, all files in .cpp are not compiled, therefore it cannot find their reference.

What I cannot understand is why the g++ compiler is not used for cpp files, while I have it: when I go to my projec properties >> C/C++ build >> ToolCahin Editor, I have as a `current toolchain` a `"GCC 5.3.0 [x86_64-w64-mingw32]"`, `current builder` = `GNU Make builder`, and in the `used tools`

- GCC C++ Compiler 5.3.0 [x86_64-w64-mingw32]
- GCC C Compiler 5.3.0 [x86_64-w64-mingw32]
- GCC Assembler 5.3.0 [x86_64-w64-mingw32]
- GCC C++ Linker 5.3.0 [x86_64-w64-mingw32]
- GCC C Linker 5.3.0  [x86_64-w64-mingw32]
- GCC Archiver 5.3.0 [x86_64-w64-mingw32]

so I have the C++ compilers, how can I activate them on my c++ files ?

When I build, in the "build" folder (build is my configuration name) I only have the objects (.o) files for .c files, not .cpp files which are never compiled

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find the answer, I let it here in case if can help someone else.
In Eclipse, the project should be converted to c/c++ one, going into file >> new >> convert to C/C++ project (adds C/C++ nature).

By doing that, in project C/C++ build setting, a section appears to handle c++. Some of the project configuration was lost in conversion (header directory path and libraries) but I can compile both C and C++ files now